# "nautilus-emblems" in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, emblem

It appears that 13.04 restored the emblem capability in "nautilus-emblems". Unfortunately the installation instructions in `/usr/share/doc/nautilus-emblems/README.md` aren't very clear:

> As `root` user copy the `.py` file in
>   `/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/`.
>
> You need to kill nautilus: `nautilus -q` and restart it again:
>   `nautilus`.

Copy to where? has anyone got this working?

Comment: I don't have a "nautilus-emblems" folder on my machine...

Comment: @Seth - you have to install the package: `sudo apt-get install nautilus-emblem`. It still doesn't give you an executable though, just a python script.

Answer (score 0):

[Those instructions](https://github.com/agonzalezro/gnome3-emblems#readme) are for manual installation, so you can ignore them since you're installing from [a package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-emblems/) instead.

Installing the package *should* be the only thing you need to do. However, there's currently an unrelated [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1170017) that's preventing nautilus-emblems from being loaded.

### Solution

The bug [has been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-python/+bug/1170017/comments/13) in what will become Ubuntu 13.10. If you wait until October and then upgrade Ubuntu, nautilus-emblems should work.

There's been no indication yet of plans to release a fix for Ubuntu 13.04.

### Temporary workaround

If you're feeling adventurous, you can try building the unreleased package for Ubuntu 13.04:

1. Install `build-essential`, `debian-keyring`, and the [build dependencies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Installation_commands) for `python-nautilus`.
2. Save the three [source package downloads](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-python/1.1-3ubuntu3) to a temporary location and run:

   ```
   dpkg-source -x nautilus-python_1.1-3ubuntu3.dsc
   cd nautilus-python-1.1
   dpkg-buildpackage -b
   ```
3. Install `python-nautilus_1.1-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb`.